# How to i post image id to php along with $_FILE

Tags: php, forms, post, image-uploading

index.html with form tag

```
<input type='file' name='picture' id='".$row['sfname']."'onchange='javascript:ajaxFileUpload(this);'/>`
```

ajax code

```
function ajaxFileUpload(upload_field)
{
    // Checking file type
    var re_text = /\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg/i;
    var filename = upload_field.value;

    if (filename.search(re_text) == -1) {
        alert("File should be either jpg or gif or jpeg");
        upload_field.form.reset();
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('picture_preview').innerHTML = '<div><img src="ajax-loader.gif" border="0" /></div>';`
    upload_field.form.action = 'upload-picture.php';
    upload_field.form.target = 'upload_iframe';
    upload_field.form.submit();
    upload_field.form.action = '';
    upload_field.form.target = '';
    return true;
}
```

upload.php

```
<?php


?>
```

I want $row['sfname'] in index.html to be accessed along with $_FILE variable here but how can I get the script to store the image in given folder so that I can store the path in the respective user record.

I have tested the upload.php by uploading the files successfully to the file system, now I want the file path to be stored in the sql table. For that I need the user first name the same I get it from the same

My question is; How do I access the input tag ID using the above ajax code to upload.php?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply put $row['sfname'] as a value of a hidden field as your JavaScript is submitting the whole form?

```
<input type='hidden' name='sfname' value='" . $row['sfname'] . "'>
```